# How to use boost::fusion::transform on heterogeneous containers?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

Boost.org's [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/transformation/functions/transform.html) given for fusion::transform is as follows:

```
struct triple
{
    typedef int result_type;

    int operator()(int t) const
    {
        return t * 3;
    };
};
// ...
assert(transform(make_vector(1,2,3), triple()) == make_vector(3,6,9));
```

Yet I'm not "getting it."  The vector in their example contains elements all of the same type, but a major point of using fusion is containers of heterogeneous types.  What if they had used `make_vector(1, 'a', "howdy")` instead?

`int operator()(int t)`
would need to become
`template<typename T> T& operator()(T& const t)`

But how would I write the result_type? `template<typename T> typedef T& result_type` certainly isn't valid syntax, and it wouldn't make sense even if it was, because it's not tied to the function.

Comment: Are you sure that the result_type is required, rather than because the guy likes to put it in there? In the example above, he appears to be using a primitive form of decltype to form the result type.

Comment: ugh, you're right, it's not required. Thanks.  I'm going to post a new question asking for a real guide to boost::fusion, this documentation on boost.org is barely a step above reading the code itself.. Grrr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, fusion::transform is used with a templated (or -as shown above- otherwise overloaded) function operator:

```
struct triple 
{ 
    template <typename Sig>
    struct result;

    template <typename This, typename T>
    struct result<This(T)>
    {
        typedef /*...figure out return type...*/ type;
    };

    template <typename T> 
    typename result<triple(T)>::type 
    operator()(T t) const 
    { 
        return 3*t;    // relies on existing operator*() for 'T'
    }
};
```

And, additional sources of information about Fusion are the examples and the test directory where you can find demonstrations of some of the techniques.

Regards Hartmut

Comment: Specifically, <boost>/libs/fusion/test/algorithm/transform.cpp -- I had no idea these test files existed.  Thanks!

Comment: `boost::fusion::transform` seems to fail when `F` is a c++ lambda. Is this a known issue or am I failing to invoke it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overloading the call operator()?

```
struct triple
{

    int operator()(int t) const
    {
        return t * 3;
    };
    int operator()(string t) const
    {
        return t + t + t;
    };
};
```